# Hybrid parallelization with OpenMP and MPI

Tags: multithreading, mpi, openmp, openmpi, pbs

I'm trying to setup a program which runs across a cluster of 20 nodes, each with 12 cores each. The idea is to have the head process distribute some data out to each node, and have each node perform some operations on the data using OpenMP to utilize the 12 cores. I'm relatively new to this an not sure about the best way to set this up.

We use PBS as the scheduler and my original plan was to create a single MPI process on each node, and let OpenMP create 12 threads per node.

```
#PBS -l nodes=20:ppn=1
```

But when I run this, OpenMP seems to only create 1 thread per process. How can I set this up so OpenMP will always create 12 threads per MPI process?

Edit: As soon as I specify to use more than 1 process in PBS, OpenMP will start using 6 threads per process, can't seem to figure out why using only 1 process per node isn't working.

Comment: While there may be a generic answer for PBS, I would highly recommend consulting the documentation of your cluster or asking the operators. Many clusters run customized resource managers or combinations that make it difficult to give a generic answer.

Comment: Agree with Zulan. Also mpi/openmp runtimes have their own specific environment variables which also varies from different runtime versions. In brief so many variables, few data you provide in the question but your sysadmins are likely to know.